# Flashbuilder 4.5. Parse results of HTTP Service Call

Tags: httpservice, flash-builder4.5

I'm making an HTTP Service Call using Flash Builder 4.5. My web service returns a string. I'm having trouble understanding how to read in the returned string.

```
LoginResult.token = login.Login(Username.text, Password.text);
```

Here is what I have so far. What do I need to do next to get the returned string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. In case this will help anyone else, the following gets you the String returned by the HTTP Service Call.

```
LoginResult.token = login.Login(Username.text, Password.text);    
LoginResult.lastResult //String returned by web service
```